# Change Rich Text Box Bullet Indentation

Tags: wpf

I have a RTB control in my WPF application. Is there a way to adjust the indentation when the EditingCommands.ToggleBullets command is executed? Maybe adjusting a marker style (if such a thing exists) for the RTB, or something I'm not quite aware of?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending if you need to adjust indentation of the bulleted list, single list item, spacing between bullet and text or something else, you can experiment with Padding, Margin, or Paragraph.TextIndent. Consider this example:

```
    <RichTextBox Name="rbox">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Span>List here:</Span>
            </Paragraph>
            <List Padding="10,0,0,0">
                <ListItem>
                    <Paragraph TextIndent="0" Margin="0">An item</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

List apparently has some default padding value that pushes the items to the right. Remove the explicit Padding in above example from List to see how it looks.

Also check out Flow Document Overview on MSDN.

Comment: OK, so this answer got me on the right path. The paragraph's textindent and the list margin just tacked on space with the bullet, which didn't help me. However, I started tinkering with the padding list style. Set to 0...the bullet didn't even show up. Nor did the command to display bullet formatting work...setting it to a small value resulted in the same behavior. Once I hard-set the value to 15, I began to get the behavior that I wanted. I'm curious about why this is the case, but I can work with this, thanks!